# Globally (preamble) set the width of all tables in a document

Tags: tables

Is there a way to globally (such as in the preamble) define the width of all tables in a document? My goal is to have all tables set to the `\textwidth`. My content source is markdown, and I'm using pandoc to convert to latex which ultimately goes into pdflatex.

I've done searching on this but cant find a straight answer. One method suggested I create a a pandoc filter to replace all my tables with a tabularx, but this seems overly complicated. Any suggestions?

Comment: stretching the columns apart makes the table a lot less readable, but if you want to do it anyway, you need to use `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}`  instead of `\begin{tabular}` everywhere but I'm not sure how you configure pandoc to do that

Answer (score 1):

Pandoc uses [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable), so you can set the margins of your tables with:

```
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} 
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
```

Add those lines to a file and call pandoc with the option `--include-in-header=FILE`, this aligns your table left and right if possible. You now should add `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` to your longtable environments, which does not work out of the box, since `pandoc` generates those automatically and there is no easy way to change how. Maybe you could write a [filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) for that...